# Can/Could have done = Can/Could it be so that

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-constructions, could-modal

I recently saw such a phrase:

***I can have done it***

Can it be a contraction of

***It can be so that I have done it*** ?

The same with

***I could have done it = It could be so that I had done it***

Or these contractions and, as I call them, full phrases are totally different and so is their meaning?

Comment: The first sentence is quite unlikely: the only context I can think of where it might be said is talking about a future time by which you can do something; but it is much more natural to say "I'll do it by (whenever)". I don't know what you are trying to achieve by your "full phrases": I guess they mean the same, with the same range of possibilities.

Comment: So, we can't say "I don't know where she is. She can have left" = "I don't know where she is. It can be thus that she has left"? They seem totaly the same due to sense.

Comment: It isn't natural to use _can_ in that case: I would always use _could_, but I agree that I could say the longer as well as the natural form. If I want to make it clear that I am talking about the present, I might use _She might have left_, but not _She can have left_. However, in the negative, I could say _She can't have left_.

Comment: Okay, if it's negative can we say "She can't have left" = "It can't be so that she has left"?

Comment: I repeat: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by the longer form. Yes it has the same meaning, but it does not explain or clarify anything as far as I can see. Remember also that modals with "have" usually have an epistemic meaning, so _She can't have left_ means something like "I'm sure that she hasn't left", or "I deduce with certainty that she hasn't left".